# Maven not building reactjs files into my jar file

Tags: java, reactjs, maven, npm

I am using `exec-maven-plugin` to run my maven build to build my reactjs project into my jar file, however, it executes fine but when I go into my jar file, none of the reactjs files are present - only my java classes are present.

---

My pom.xml looks like the following:

```
<plugin>
     <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
     <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>exec-npm-install</id>
             <phase>generate-sources</phase>
             <configuration>                  
                  <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}src\main\app</workingDirectory>
                  <executable>npm.cmd</executable>
                  <arguments>
                       <argument>install</argument>
                  </arguments>
             </configuration>
             <goals>
                 <goal>exec</goal>
             </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
                    <id>exec npm build</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/app</workingDirectory>
                        <executable>npm.cmd</executable>
                        <arguments>
                            <argument>run-script</argument>
                            <argument>build</argument>                      
                        </arguments>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I don't see where you're building your React app. Just see `npm install`.

Comment: I would recommend to take a look at the [fronend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin)

Comment: @khmarbaise I did take a look at that and tried implementing it but there are proxy issues that I wasn't able to resolve.

Comment: @wdm ops updating it now